# What does this line do in Perl?

Tags: perl

What does this line do in Perl?

```
s/\s//g;
```

I'm looking at a script that is used to search and count certain characters in an input file and I understand everything in the code except for this line. I was wondering what this line did for the script?

Comment: Almost looks like the sed pattern for replacing text. See http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/09/unix-sed-tutorial-replace-text-inside-a-file-using-substitute-command/?utm_source=sitekickr&utm_medium=snip_button

Comment: Looks like it removes all whitespaces from the default `$_` variable. `s///` is text replacement, `\s` is whitespace, replacing it with nohting (as there is nothing in between the second and third slashes), and applying it everywhere (`g` for global).

Answer (score 2):

```
s/\s//g;
```

is short for

```
$_ =~ s/\s//g;
```

It is a [substitution operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html) bound to `$_`. It replaces all sequences in `$_` that match the [regex pattern](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) `\s` with nothing. (Without `g`, it would only replace the first.)

`\s` matches a character of whitespace.